# Any solution for Samsung Galaxy ICS 4.0.3 LPQ firmware sending two text messages?

Tags: android, galaxy, samsung-mobile

There is an issue with firmware (LPQ) specifically for Samsung Galaxy S2 running ICS 4.0.3 where SMS is sent twice on all 3rd party apps (including Handcent, GO SMS, etc) except stock messaging app. I think the latest version of firmware LP7 fixes the duplicate send SMS issue.

However, Handcent & GO SMS has found their own workarounds and upgraded their apks to market.

Does anyone else know how to fix this issue programmatically using sendMultipartTextMessage() or/and sendTextMessage()?

thanks!

Comment: I have read that using sendMultipartTextMessage works. Just wrap your texts etc in a List and try it :)

Comment: @zapl - I am currently using sendMultipartTextMessage and wrapping the messages in a list, but still sends same text messages twice.

Comment: There are varius issue also in the 2.3.6 rom for this device... It seems that Samsung is changing/customizing the SMS send API functions in all newer ROMs and thus creating bugs all over the place...

Comment: Still hunting for a solution. Has no one found a solution yet?

Comment: Wasn't LPQ a leaked ROM and not an official one? You really should be moving away from it. More info: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1559141

Answer (score 1):

Check out the workaround at the official bug report http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=27024#c23

And the Android Library project that wraps the workaround in a nice consistent API: https://github.com/nadam/compatibility-sms-manager

Answer (score 0):

There's an option to check if you are using a Samsung in the

> settings>send message